# How to handle transition for a newly selected card, in react, when the dom is displaying either full set of cards or just the one selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/itsMGA/eliptum-react/select-service-functionality?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522GIT%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6u1r0507py2a66s6ar7mm5%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6u1r0507pp2a66288woasf%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6u1r0507pv2a66q79mr7zw%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6u1r0507px2a66simmlkea%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clr6u1r0507pp2a66288woasf%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6u1r0507po2a66kgl82pxa%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6u1r0507pp2a66288woasf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr6u1r0507po2a66kgl82pxa%2522%257D%252C%2522clr6u1r0507px2a66simmlkea%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6u1r0507px2a66simmlkea%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6u7cn6009k2a6656lnrm5m%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2523%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr6u7cn6009k2a6656lnrm5m%2522%257D%252C%2522clr6u1r0507pv2a66q79mr7zw%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6u1r0507pv2a66q79mr7zw%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clr6u1r0507pq2a665xn95oo8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clr6u1r0507pq2a665xn95oo8%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

So I use these states to track which card is selected and a function that updates the states:

```
  const [selectedServiceIndex, setSelectedServiceIndex] = useState(null);

  const [isServiceSelected, setIsServiceSelected] = useState(false);

  const handleServiceClick = (index) => {
    console.log("Clicked service index:", index); // Add a log to track the index clicked

    if (index >= 0 && index < services_data.length) {
      // Check if index is within range
      if (isServiceSelected && selectedServiceIndex === index) {
        setIsServiceSelected(false); // If already selected, deselect
        console.log(false);
      } else {
        setSelectedServiceIndex(index);
        setIsServiceSelected(true); // Select the service
        console.log(true);
      }
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid index or index out of range");
    }
  };
```

Creating the cards component as services:

```
  const services = services_data.map((item, index) => (
<div key={index} onClick={() => handleServiceClick(index)}>
  <Service
    name={item.name}
    imageName={item.imageName}
    className={item.className}
    desc={item.desc}
  />
</div>
));
```

Here I render the services, initially, all 3 services are displayed:

```
return (
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
      </head>
      <body>
        <main>
          <div>
            <link
              rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css"
              integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA=="
              crossOrigin="anonymous"
              referrerPolicy="no-referrer"
            />
            {!isServiceSelected ? (
              <section className="section services-section" id="services">
                <div className="container">
                  <div className="row">
                    <div className="page-header">
                      <div className="section-title">
                        <h2>Services</h2>
                        <p>
                          Enhance efficiency, reliability, and quality with
                          automated test solutions.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row services-row">{services}</div>
                </div>
              </section>
            ) : (
              <div
                className={`selected-service ${
                  isServiceSelected ? "active" : ""
                }`}
              >
                {services[selectedServiceIndex]}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
```

By clicking on any of them, will cause this isServiceSelected boolean to toggle true/false

If false, all services are shown `<div className="row services-row">{services}</div>' else, only the selected one is displayed using the index of the selected service`             {services[selectedServiceIndex]}`

Now, everything works as expected, clicking a service makes the whole initial content dissapear, and just that one service remains, top of the page, clicking again, brings back the initial content, with header and all services

Problem is how do i style this to fade out or anything, now i m questioning if my approach was any good, seems like it was a bad idea to start with

Bcs, doing it like so, the content is changed, and if i want to fade out everything under               `<section className="section services-section" id="services">` will not work bcs the section itself is not present anymore

I m not asking for anybody to code this for me, i just need some advice on how to tackle this problem

I cannot provide a basic working example bcs, this is using react, so I'll have to link a sandbox  reference, which contains a stripped version of the app so its easier to look at

Answer (score 1):

So for fade-in / fade-out animations a simple solution would be to keep all elements in the DOM and just set their opacity depending if they should be shown or not. Then add CSS transition to make the fading in and out smooth.

This is a simple solution but might not be the best performance-wise, depending how many other elements are rendered in the DOM on the same page.

Depending on how the transitions between the services should look like, another approach might be something like this:
When the user selects a different service, first a isServiceVisible state is being set to false. This sets the opacity of your "selected-service" div to 0. "selected-service" also needs to have a transition for opacity, for 0.5 seconds for example ("transition: opacity 0.5s").
Then set a timeout for 0.5s seconds, which when it ends will both: Update setSelectedServiceIndex to the service the user selected and also updates isServiceVisible again to be true, so the new service will fade in.

Just a code snippet as an example:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [isServiceVisible, setIsServiceVisible] = useState(true);
    const [selectedService, setSelectedService] = useState('home');

    const handleSelectService = () => {
        setIsServiceVisible(false);
        setTimeout(() => {
            setSelectedService('products');
            setIsServiceVisible(true);
        }, 500);
    };

    return (
        <div className="selected-service" style={{ opacity: isServiceVisible ? 1 : 0, transition: 'opacity 0.5s' }}>

        </div>
    )
}
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.

BTW: Using setTimeout might cause unwanted side-effects if not handled properly, so be sure to clear the timeout if the components unmounts.